# Dynamically add input to RapidMiner through Java

Tags: java, rapidminer

I need to dynamically input files into my java application and use rapidminer for classification. I have the following code:

```
RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(RapidMiner.ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
          RapidMiner.init();

          Process process = new Process(new File("C:\\Users\\nelze\\.RapidMiner5      \\repositories\\WalkingRepo\\NaiveClassify.rmp"));
          Operator op = process.getOperator("Read CSV");
          op.setParameter(com.rapidminer.operator.nio.CSVExampleSource.PARAMETER_CSV_FILE, "C:\\Users\\nelze\\unlabeled (2).csv");
          //ioInput.append(op);
          IOContainer ioResult = process.run();
          ExampleSet resultSet1 = (ExampleSet)ioResult.getElementAt(0);
          Iterator<Attribute> allAttributes = resultSet1.getAttributes().allAttributes();
```

However, when I run it it always says "input file not defined."

In my RapidMiner process, the input port is connected to the READ CSV operator.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think you should not connect the input port to the input of the Read CSV, as it accepts the file object there when those are connected, which you do not seem to supply.

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by that? I am supplying the file name in setParameter so the Read CSV operator can use that file, right?

Comment: I mean in your process "the input port is connected to the READ CSV operator", so the setParameter is not interesting, it is expecting the file from the input port.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `Read CSV` operator is connected to the input port of the process (the top port on the left hand side, labelled `inp`.) If that is true, the parameter `csv file` is no longer used (it should also be hidden in the UI). Instead, the file sent to the input port is used. There are two solutions:

1. Disconnect that port and set the parameter as you do it in your code.
2. Keep the port connected and send the file object into the process, so it goes from the input port to the `Read CSV` operator. Modify your code like so:

   ```
   FileObject file = new SimpleFileObject(new File(".../unlabeled (2).csv"));
   IOContainer input = new IOContainer(file);
   IOContainer ioResult = process.run(input);
   ```